# Converting Excel date to Moment date gives a wrong year output

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am working on importing data in an Excel file and it has date column.
In my app, that date column value comes as a serial number like `43101.622083333335` which stands for `01/01/2018`.

When converting this serial number from Excel back to the normal date it stands for, it gives wrong year.
For example, it gives `01-Jan-1970` instead of `01-Jan-2018`
``

```
var moment = require('moment');
var excelDate = 43101.622083333335;
var date = moment(new Date(excelDate));
var dateWithNewFormat = date.format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
console.log(dateWithNewFormat);
```

``

Output: `01-Jan-1970` instead of `01-Jan-2018`

Any help ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with the `moment` library. It seems that you aren't calling `Date` with a valid constructor argument with `new Date(excelDate)` (see official documentation for `Date` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

The `Date` class doesn't understand the concept of 'Excel time' but it does understand the concept of a unix timestamp. If you refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6154953/11281137), you can see how to convert from Excel time to a unix timestamp, depending on which version of Excel you are using.

Then, I would change your code to:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var excelDate = 43101.622083333335;
var unixTimestamp = (excelDate-25569)*86400 //as per the post above, convert Excel date to unix timestamp, assuming Mac/Windows Excel 2011 onwards
var date = moment(new Date(unixTimestamp)); //Pass in unix timestamp instead of Excel date
var dateWithNewFormat = date.format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
console.log(dateWithNewFormat);
```

Comment: thanks for helping but i updated your answer  with the help of this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943089/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-calendar-date-moment-js to get the required output.

Comment: The `var unixTimestamp = (excelDate-25569)*86400` line should really be `var unixTimestamp = (excelDate-25569)*86400000` -- the offset value needs to be multiplied by milliseconds per hour.