# Converting Unix Timestamp to readable time from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling data from Firebase to chart it on my application. Right now the chart works fine, the y axis shows the proper data but the x axis shows the unix timestamps since that's what my array of data has, how can I convert this to readable time before it gets charted? I've looked into moment.js but I'm not sure where I would apply that.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        words: [],
      options: {
              chart: {
              },   
              legend: {
                position: 'top',
                horizontalAlign: 'right',
                floating: true,
                offsetY: -25,
                offsetX: -5
              }
            },
    };
  };


  componentDidMount() {
  this.renderCharts();
  };

  renderCharts() {
    const wordRef = firebase.database().ref('MyFireBaseDB');
    wordRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      let words = snapshot.val();
      let myState = [];
      for (let word in words) {
        myState.push({
          x: word, ///This is grabbing the Unix timestamps from database///
          y: words[word], ///My y-axis data points///
        })
      }
  this.setState({
    arr: myState,
  })
  });
  }

render() {
      const series = [{
      name: "Chart Data",
      data: this.state.arr
  },
  ];

                        return (
                  <div className='App'>

  <Chart options={this.state.options} series={series} type="line" width={'100%'} height={320} />

                  </div>


              );

      }
  }
```

Here is what the array of data looks like and right now the chart works fine, but the X axis shows the unix timestamp, how can I convert to readable time before it gets charted?

```
[{"x":"1574342743","y":196},{"x":"1574343390","y":176},{"x":"1574344052","y":121},{"x":"1574344721","y":114}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert unix timestamp to calendar date moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943089/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-calendar-date-moment-js)

Comment: I seen that, but I'm not sure where I could use that in my code. I tried using it right in the myState.push but it says I can't use a function in that.

Comment: `word = moment.unix(word).format("MM/DD/YYYY");` before `myState.push({`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var timestamp = "0"; //string timestamp 
var d = new Date(+timestamp); //cast to int
console.log(d.toLocaleString());
//1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```