# Transform moment timestamp into different format string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Transform moment timestamp into different format string

Hi everybody, moment is giving me a timestamp like this:

```
2022-03-24T15:22:02.239Z
```

And I want to get a string formatted like this:

```
"May 25, 2022 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert unix timestamp to calendar date moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943089/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-calendar-date-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `format` method provided to do this.

For this scenario try

```
moment().format("MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss a");
```

See documentation for moment here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/